# Issue with the producing wrong output value in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wrote the PHP code that calculates the school grade (including weight and targeting grade), however, it produces the wrong output value.

Here's my PHP code so far..

```
<?php

$numassignments = isset($_GET['numassignments']) ? $_GET['numassignments'] : 0;

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Lab 01 - Final Grade Calculator</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mt-5">Final Grade Calculator</h1>
        <p>Welcome to the Final Grade Calculator!</p>
        <div class="alert alert-info mb-5">
            <h2 class="form-text fs-4 mb-4">To get started, please enter the number of assignments that you've completed so far.</h2>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="numassignments" class="form-label">Number of Assignments:</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numassignments" id="numassignments" min="1" max="10" value="<?php echo $numassignments ?>" required>
                    </div>
                    <p class="form-text">How many assignments have you already completed in this course?</p>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate Rows" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

[image]
Enter the input value and hit 'Generate Row' to produce the input rows in the second form field. For me, I put 3.

```
<!-- Second form -->
        <?php if (isset($_GET['numassignments']) && $_GET['numassignments'] > 0) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info mb-5">
                <h2 class="form-text fs-4 mb-4">Next, for each assignment, add the grade that you received and the assignment's overall weight.</h2>
                <!-- PHP_SELF is the name of the current file WITHOUT any query string info. To retain the query string info, we can use REQUEST_URI -->
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <?php

                        $desired = isset($_POST["desired"]) ? $_POST["desired"] : 0;

                        for ($i = 1; $i <= $numassignments; $i++) {
                            echo "<div class=\"row\">";
                            echo "\n<div class=\"col-md-6\">"; //grade input
                            echo "\n<div class=\"mb-3\">";
                            echo "\n<label for=\"keep-numassignments{$i}\" class=\"form-label\">Assignment " . $i . " Grade:</label>";
                            echo "\n<input type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"keep-numassignments[$i]\" id=\"keep-numassignments{$i}\" min=\"0\" max=\"100\" value=\"$keep_numassignments\" required>";
                            echo "\n</div>";
                            echo "\n</div>";
                            echo "\n<div class=\"col-md-6\">"; //weight input
                            echo "\n<div class=\"mb-3\">";
                            echo "\n<label for=\"weightnum{$i}\" class=\"form-label\">Assignment " . $i . " Weight:</label>";
                            echo "\n<input type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"weightnum[$i]\" id=\"weightnum{$i}\" min=\"1\" max=\"100\" value=\"$weightnum\" required>";
                            echo "\n</div>";
                            echo "\n</div>";
                            echo "\n</div>";
                        }
                        ?>
                        <p class="form-text">Finally, if you would like to calculate what you will need to get on the remainder of your coursework in order to receive a certain grade, enter your desired grade below.</p>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="desired" class="form-label">Desired Final Grade (Optional):</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="desired" id="desired" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $desired; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="submit" name="gradesubmit" value="Calculate Grade" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['gradesubmit'])) {
            // Retrieve the values from the form
            $grades = isset($_POST["keep-numassignments"]) ? $_POST["keep-numassignments"] : [];
            $weights = isset($_POST["weightnum"]) ? $_POST["weightnum"] : [];

            $desired = isset($_POST["desired"]) ? $_POST["desired"] : 0;

            // Calculate the weighted average of completed assignments
            $weightedSum = 0;
            $totalWeight = 0;

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($grades); $i++) {
                $weightedSum += ($weights[$i] * $grades[$i]);
                $totalWeight += $weights[$i];
            }

            $currentAverage = ($totalWeight > 0) ? ($weightedSum / $totalWeight) : 0;

            // Calculate the required grade on remaining assessments
            if ($totalWeight < 100 && $desired > 0) {
                $remainingWeight = 100 - $totalWeight;
                $requiredGrade = ($desired - (1 - ($remainingWeight / 100)) * $currentAverage) / $remainingWeight;
            } else {
                $requiredGrade = 0;
            }

            // Display the results
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success mb-5\">";
            echo "\n<p>Current Class Average: " . number_format($currentAverage, 2) . "%</p>";
            if ($desired > 0) {
                echo "\n<p>Required Grade on Remaining Assessments: " . number_format($requiredGrade, 2) . "%</p>";
            }
            echo "\n</div>";
        }

        ?>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

[image]

I put the input value like in the picture, but the wrong value was output.
If it had been calculated correctly, the output would be produced 61.67% for the Current Class Average, and 135% for the Required Grade on Remaining Assessments.

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mixing up the list indices for numassignments when your adding items and when your reading items.

When you're adding items to the list you start at 1

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numassignments; $i++)
```

When you're reading items from the list you start at 0

```
$grades = isset($_POST["keep-numassignments"]) ? $_POST["keep-numassignments"] : [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($grades); $i++) {
                $weightedSum += ($weights[$i] * $grades[$i]);
                $totalWeight += $weights[$i];
            }
```

If you check the average of your first two items (50, 65) you get the average of 57.5% that you're seeing in your output.

To fix this, I would start reading your grades and weights starting from index 1 just like when you added them.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($grades); $i++) {
                $weightedSum += ($weights[$i] * $grades[$i]);
                $totalWeight += $weights[$i];
            }
```